# String Comparison Fails Java

Tags: java, android, string

I am unsure why my String comparison is failing.

I have a TextView which I am updating as a user clicks a button. The letter of the button appears in the TextView. That part works.

I have a TextWatcher on my TextView which listens using `afterTextChanged(Editable arg0)` that sends the TextView and another string for comparison. If the comparison is true, it sends it to another method. However, regardless of how I compare them, it always fails.

Here is what I have tried:

```
public void checkText(String textView, String wordVar){

    Log.d("checkText","Got the word " + textView.toString() + ". Checking against " + wordVar.toString()); //debug log to compare string values by printing them
    if(textView.toString().equals(wordVar.toString())){
        Log.d("Match","Matches, changing word"); //debug log to notify me when they match
        try {
            newWord();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
 }
```

I have also tried other variations, such as `textView.equals(wordVar)` and `textView.toString() == wordVar.toString()` but niether of those work.

How else can I compare the strings and have it return true?

**Edit**: Fair Enough. LogCat below.

Here is my text listener:

```
textView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        check.checkWord(textView.getText().toString(), wordVar);
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) { }
});
```

LogCat Output:

```
07-26 21:42:20.398: D/Got(1058): Got the word B. Checking against Begin 
07-26 21:42:21.361: D/Got(1058): Got the word Be. Checking against Begin 
07-26 21:42:23.378: D/Got(1058): Got the word Beg. Checking against Begin
07-26 21:42:24.979: D/Got(1058): Got the word Begi. Checking against Begin 
07-26 21:42:25.828: D/Got(1058): Got the word Begin. Checking against Begin
```

So they are both coming over as a string, but I feel like I have tried every comparison style available between Objects and Strings and even when they match in the debug output, the if statement isn't fired. Or if it is, it fails.

Comment: Don't forget, String comparison is case sensitive

Comment: Are there any leading or trailing whitespace characters?  If so, `trim()` them.

Comment: So, what are the two values that are logged by your `Log.d()` call? And why are you calling toString() on a String? Why not call wordVar.toString().toString().toString().toString() while you're at it?

Comment: I took it seriously. You have a Log.d() call that prints the value of the two strings. So, what is logged by this call? Without having this information, we can't give any good answer other than "maybe you have spaces" or "maybe you need a case-insensitive comparison".

Comment: Fair Enough, i added the LogCat. The period is part of the debug string i put together, and not part of the string i am sending.

Comment: Add a period at the end of your log statement, to see if there's a trailing space in the wordVar value. You could also add other useful debugging info, like the length of both strings. Or print out the integer value of each of their character.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for the suggestion, looks like there was a space in the `wordVar` value. The lengths ended up being different, and it was a trailing space. As an apology for calling you out, toss an answer in there and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the debug session showed it, there was a trailing space in one of the variables being compared.

Here's a list of things that can help spot bugs like this:

- use a debugger to inspect the values
- add logging traces to the code, and read them
- surround the values by delimiters : `Log.d("|" + value + "|");` to spot trailing spaces
- also log the length of the strings
- if they really look the same, but aren't equal, loop through their chars and print their integer values. Some chars print the same way, but aren't the same (like non-breakable spaces and spaces, for example)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're taking in the parameters as `Strings`, so don't use the `toString()` method on them.

It's as simple as this and this is not wrong:

`if(textView.equals(wordVar))`

Anything that is going wrong is somewhere else in your code (case sensitive Strings, incorrect Strings, leading or trailing spaces, etc.).